# Proper use of IBOutlets in Storyboard using MVC design pattern

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

Following the MVC design pattern for iOS apps using Storyboards in Xcode, I noticed that I can place IBOutlets for UILabels, UIImageViews, etc., into the ViewController or into the UIView itself.

Scenario 1:

Model Classes -> View Controllers (IBOutlets) -> UIViews in Storyboard Scene

- the ViewController (VC) grabs the necessary data from the Model
- IBOutlets in the VC are used to set the text and images that are in various UIViews in the Storyboard

Scenario 2:

Model Classes -> View Controllers -> UIViews in Storyboard (IBOutlets)

- the VC grabs the data from the Model
- the VC calls methods in each UIView subclass
- those methods in each UIView subclass set the text and images in the associated UIView via the IBOutlets in that UIView

I found that Scenario 2 is more manageable when you have many UIViews and UILabels and UIImageViews in each view.  The other approach can lead to a lot of IBOutlets in a single View Controller.

Which approach is best to follow when using Storyboards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observation is correct, the second scenario leads to a more manageable design.

The difference between your two scenarios is primarily in their use of encapsulation: the first scenario encapsulates on the level of View+View Controller, letting the controller freely access things that should logically be part of the view alone, while the second scenario properly restricts access of `IBOutlets` to the view class, forcing the view controller to interact with them through the methods that you expose in your view.

As the consequence, the first scenario creates tight coupling between the view and its controller, while the second scenario significantly reduces this coupling.

Of course there is a tradeoff: you pay for reduced coupling with more code. Up to a certain point, it does not matter: when your views and their controllers are relatively small, it is easy to manage the combination of the view and its associated view controller as a monolithic object. The benefits of using the second scenario become more visible as the complexity of your views increases. This applies to all uses of encapsulation, not only to MVS in iOS scenario: the bigger your project - the more payoff you get from using proper encapsulation.

Comment: So basically the 1st scenario for simple storyboard scenes and the 2nd scenario for complicated scenes that contain multiple uiviews?

Comment: Well that makes sense, thanks for the help. If you know of any resources on applying MVC to larger iOS projects with Storyboards then please post some links in your answer.